# SQL Bounding Box Optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

Can anybody link to any documents regarding optimized bounding box style queries in SQL?

At the most basic level, imagine an table consisting of x,y float columns, we query the table for rows within a certain (x1,x2),(y1,y2) range.  The query to do this is trivial, but what is the best way to define the indexes to ensure this query behaves efficiently?

We could simply create an index on the x and y columns, or I could create an index on both the x and y columns, but I don't know enough about SQL indexing to reason my way through this.

I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

A space filling curve is best to reduce a 2d space to a 1d problem. It's constructed like a fractal and is basically a gray code traversal of the surface. Instead of calculate an index you can put together a quadtree path prefix-free key similar to a huffman code. Then you can use a simple string query to retrieve a box. MySql has a spatial index extension but I don't know what curve they use. It's probably the simple z-curve or the peano curve. You can take a look at Nick spatial index quadtree hilbert curve blog. Monotonic n-ary gray code can also be very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

[mysqls spatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html)

it can use [r tree indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree)

then you have handy functions like [mbrwithin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html#function_mbrwithin)

seems right up your alley